# Php inside foreach loop if $i == 1 echo "ok", else echo "ok" JUST one time and continue

Tags: php

its been a while (5 years) since my last time here making questions.

I need help, I'm developing an event calendar and I'm stuck in this.
I want to have event header and event body, so far so good, but I just want one header if there are more than one event in each day.
So today I've a dinner at 21h, my event should have Friday , November 23 and Dinner at 21h.
Perfect, I can do this, but what about if I do have a meeting before dinner, at 19h?
I want just one time the same header ... Friday, November 23 but 2 bodies...

thanks!

my piece of code

```
foreach($eventos[$data_do_dia] as $evento) {
    $i = count($eventos[$data_do_dia]);
    if($i == 1) {
       $agenda .= " dia ".date("d-m-Y",strtotime($evento['dia']))."</b>";
       add the event
    } else {
        repeat the same but just one time
        $agenda .= " dia ".date("d-m-Y",strtotime($evento['dia']))."</b>";

        add event one
        add event two
        ...     
    }
}
```

Comment: If `$eventos[$data_do_dia]` is an array of events for a single day, then can't you just output the header *before* the loop?

Comment: I think I can't... this is the print_r of my test array Array ( [0] => Array ( [dia] => 2018-11-19 [hora] => 09:30 [titulo] => Título do evento para o dia 19/11/2018 [evento] => Texto do evento do dia 19/11/2018 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [dia] => 2018-11-20 [hora] => 11:30 [titulo] => Título do evento do dia 20/11/2018 [evento] => Texto do evento do dia 20/11/2018 ) [1] => Array ( [dia] => 2018-11-20 [hora] => 14:00 [titulo] => Novo evento no dia 20 [evento] => Novo evento para o dia 20 de Novembro de 2018 ) ). I loop the array and get $evento['hora'], $evento['evento'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the loop so that there isn't any repeated code, this basically means that if there is only one event, it converts into an array, assuming that `isset($evento[0])` will pick up there aren't sub-arrays, it wraps the one entry into a new array.

It then loops over the array and creates the string with the date/time/details.  You will probably want to change the format, but the principle is the same...

```
$agenda = "";
foreach($eventos as $evento) {
    if ( !isset($evento[0]) )    {
        $evento = [$evento];
    }
    $agenda .= " dia ".date("d-m-Y",strtotime($evento[0]['dia'])).PHP_EOL;
    foreach ( $evento as $time )    {
        $agenda .= " time ".$time['hora']." ".
            $time['titulo']." ".$time['evento'].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
echo $agenda;
```

Comment: Thanks! works perfect, I haven't think on foreach inside foreach.